# Any limit on number of Matrix Blocks?

Tags: matrix

I have run into an issue where the following code will only return 100 blocks, despite the fact that there are more. Is there some limit I am not aware of? Running the latest version.

`{% for block in entry.supporters.type('individuals').order('firstName') %}`

Answer (score 6):

Every criteria model in Craft 2 has a limit set to 100 by default. You can override it by setting a `limit` parameter on the model.

```
{% for block in entry.supporters.type('individuals').order('firstName').limit(null) %}
```